# SQL ORACLE Using a point in a column with using htf (hypertext functions)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm working on SQL ORACLE DATABASE and I create a table than going into foor loob and working with htf for convert table to html formate.

```
create table show_mail (id number, data varchar2(25));
insert into show_mail values(101, 'one hundred & one')
insert into show_mail values(202, 'two hundred & two')
insert into show_mail values(303, 'three hundred & three')


DECLARE
v_html VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEOPEN('border="1px"');
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEHEADER('ID.DATA');
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM show_mail) LOOP
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWOPEN;
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEDATA((i.id));
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEDATA(HTF.ESCAPE_SC(i.data));  
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLEROWCLOSE;
END LOOP;
v_html := v_html || HTF.TABLECLOSE;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_html);
end;
```

I wrote this code and result like that;

```
ID.DATA
  101   numberone
  202   numbertwo
  303   numberthree
```

However I want to see like;

```
ID.DATA
101.numberone
202.numbertwo
303.numberthree
```

Is it possible that numbers point and writing together?

Comment: What if just write `HTF.TABLEDATA(i.id||'.'||i.data);` ?

Comment: Perfect. You are awesome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenate values and write them `HTF.TABLEDATA(i.id||'.'||i.data);`